# get all number closest to a given value

Tags: python

Given a list of integers, I want to add to a list all numbers close to a number I give in input:

```
my_list=[1,5,35,36.3,38,42,44.1,44.8,48,61,70]
my_number=45
```

I dont want the closest number but all number who are in the range [my_number-10;my_number+10] so here [35;55]

The list I want:

```
result=[35,36.3,38,42,44.1,44.8,48]
```

Comment: `result = [i for i in my_list if my_number-10 <= i <= my_number+10]`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: do what @ChrisOram said, wrapping it in `sorted()` if you need the list to be ordered, which is what I suppose given your expected output

Comment: Also note, your initial list are not all integers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use numpy I would recommend it as we can then avoid using loops

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(my_list)

def inRange(arr, val, span):
    return arr[(arr > (val-span)) * (arr < (val+span))]

val = 45
span = 10
newArr = inRange(arr, val, span)
>>> print(newArr)
array([36.3, 38. , 42. , 44.1, 44.8, 48. ])
```

If you're not able to use `numpy` then ChrisOram's comment on the OP's question looks to be the best solution.

Comment: Using the overhead of `numpy` for this task seems like overkill. Don't optimize until you you have proof that your current solution is really slower than an alternate version (and that the time difference matters).